# How to write inner class test method in Python with Unittest

Tags: python, tdd, inner-classes, python-unittest

In Java when doing unit testing it is common to have a test class that contains multiple inner classes for each method of the class to test. Each inner class can have multiple testing methods to test a specific functionality of the related method.

I am trying to do the same thing in Python with unittest, but it seems that the inner classes' methods are not executed. For example:

```
import unittest

class OuterTestClass(unittest.TestCase):

    print("start outer class")

    def test_should_do_something(self):

            self.assertTrue( True )

            print("outer method test completed")

    class InnerTestClass(unittest.TestCase):

        print("start inner class")

        def test_should_do_something(self):

            self.assertTrue( True )

            print("inner method test completed")
```

Expected behavior:

```
> start outer class
> start inner class
> inner method test completed
> outer method test completed
```

Actual behavior:

```
> start outer class
> start inner class
> outer method test completed
```

Is it possible to execute the inner class methods as well with unittest ?

Comment: In Java, everything has to be in a class. That is not the case in Python. You can have free functions as tests, so using classes to hold tests is already one level of nesting. I would suggest you use `pytest` instead of `unittest`, however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a new test method in OuterTestClass that builds a suite of all test cases contained in InnerTestClass.

```
class OuterTestClass(TestCase):

    print("start outer class")

    def test_should_do_something(self):

        self.assertTrue( True )

        print("outer method test completed")

    class InnerTestClass(TestCase):

        print("start inner class")

        def test_should_do_something(self):

            self.assertTrue( True )

            print("inner method test completed")

    def test_inner_test_class(self):
        suite = unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(self.InnerTestClass)
        unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```